# tortoiseSVN Authorization Failed svn:// protocol

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using svn:// protocol and have auth-access = write.  SVN is setup on a linux server and a repository has been created.  When I use tortoise link on windows and open up the repo-browswer and enter my url: svn://user@website/repopath I can navigate.  However when I create a folder in that repopath I get an TortoiseSVN Authorization failed.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Checked my authz file again and realized that I did not have the path setup `[/]` was not entered above my users.